# Docker service not joining network specified in docker-compose without manual commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been struggling with this for a bit tonight.

I've got a docker compose file with a few services in, RabbitMQ and some sender/receiver test services.

I've stripped the `docker-compose.yml` file down to its very basics, so it's just RabbitMQ and one test service, but I'm still having the same issue: the test service isn't automatically connecting to the network, and the test service therefore fails. I've tried manually specifying a network in the compose file, but that doesn't seem to help. The moment it starts, it fails with an error.

Oddly, if I run `docker network connect <networkname> <containerID>` then `docker container start <containerID>`, it joins the network and runs as expected.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  sender:
    image: sender_test
    depends_on:
      - some-rabbit
    volumes:
      - /var/log/sender

  some-rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    hostname: some-rabbit
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
```

and the error I get in the logs of the `sender` container:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bunny-2.13.0/lib/bunny/session.rb:333:in `rescue in start': Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts (Bunny::TCPConnectionFailedForAllHosts)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bunny-2.13.0/lib/bunny/session.rb:305:in `start'
    from ./sender.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from ./sender.rb:83:in `new'
    from ./sender.rb:83:in `<main>'
W, [2018-12-29T04:00:53.179458 #1]  WARN -- #<Bunny::Session:0x55e4c3ae45b8 guest@some-rabbit:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[some-rabbit:5672]>: Could not establish TCP connection to some-rabbit:5672: Connection refused - connect(2) for 172.24.0.2:5672
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong? Happy to provide any further info as needed.

EDIT: Since it's apparently working on other systems, will post the contents of my files here:

`sender.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bunny'

class QueueAdder
  def initialize
    @connection = Bunny.new(host: 'some-rabbit', automatically_recover: false)
    @connection.start
    @channel = @connection.create_channel
  end

  def start(queue_name)
    @queue_name = queue_name
    @queue = @channel.queue(queue_name, durable: true)
    @exchange = @channel.default_exchange
  end

  def add_to_queue(message)
    @channel.default_exchange.publish(message, routing_key: @queue.name, persistent: true)
  end
end

add = QueueAdder.new
add.start('test')
6.times do |i|
  add.add_to_queue(i.to_s)
  #puts "#{i+5}"
  puts 'a'
  sleep 1
end
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1
RUN apt-get update
RUN dpkg --configure -a
ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN gem install pry bunny
WORKDIR /home/
COPY . .
CMD ["ruby", "./sender.rb"]
```

I'm building the image with `docker image build -t sender_test .` and starting docker-compose with `docker-compose up -d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `depends_on` argument only tells compose that you sender_test container depends on the other one (i.e. it needs to be spinned up after it)

but it doesn't link the containers.

to link containers, you need to use the `link` argument

try:

```
version: '3'

services:

  sender:
    image: sender_test
    depends_on:
      - some-rabbit
    volumes:
      - /var/log/sender
    links:
      - some-rabbit

  some-rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    hostname: some-rabbit
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
```

by the way, in your rabbit container, you expose the port to the host too, which you may not need (i.e. replace `- 5672:5672` with just `- 5672`) so that you only expose the container to the other container but not outside.

Edit:

more likely, it's the sender code that is not waiting for the service to be up and ready to receive connections, rather than a networking issue

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip RE the ports. I'll do that.

I just tried your solution - it sort of works - I no longer have to connect to the network manually, but I do have to run `docker container start <containerID>` manually, as it immediately stops with the same error post-compose.

One thing about the `links` thing though - I'd seen that mentioned, but has it not been deprecated in favour of `networks`?

Comment: Yeah, same one.

Comment: I just ran the exact file I have above, with ubuntu as the image instead of your sender image, and it started fine. I used curl inside the ubuntu container to curl some-rabbit:5672 and I got an answer

Comment: How odd. I've just updated my OP with my `Dockerfile`, `sender.rb` and the commands I'm using, I don't suppose it's still working on your end with that?

Comment: Quick update: I just tried quitting then reopening docker, updating docker, adding the `links` bit and removing it, adding a specific `command: ruby ./sender.rb`, no luck, same error, although it appears I don't need to do the `docker network connect` - simply typing `docker container start <containerID>` will get it running.

Comment: most likely, you're starting you sender service without first waiting for the rabbit one to be running and accepting connections

Comment: Aha! Yes, that was it. I added `restart: on-failure` to cover non-stacked deploys, and       `restart_policy:` `condition: on-failure` `delay: 10s`. That appears to have fixed it!

Thank you so so much for all your help!

Comment: "Link" is not an especially meaningful verb since Docker introduced user-defined networks.  The `docker-compose.yml` file in this answer is not functionally different from the one in the original question.

Comment: @David Maze Agreed.

Comment: @Faizan but it used to be. This is an old post